# Mysql how to sum and display as single row

Tags: mysql

I have a vote mysql table and users (user column) can vote y or n. (option column)

My table structure is like below:

```
| id | option | user | 
| 1  | y      | jack | 
| 2  | n      | jack | 
| 3  | n      | michi| 
| 4  | n      | michi|
```

What I would like to do is, select distinct user and count option and display it in a single row like below:

```
| y | n |
| 1 | 2 |
```

I tried GROUP_CONCAT() and SUM but without luck. Can you please help me to get this sql working?

Thanks.

Comment: E.g. `SELECT SUM(y>0)y,SUM(n>0)n FROM (SELECT user, SUM(optionyn='y')y,SUM(optionyn='n') n FROM my_table GROUP BY user)a;` - athough I prefer Rocket's first solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Group* functions like `GROUP_CONCAT()`, `SUM()` and `COUNT()` need a `GROUP BY` statement to know which rows to combine.

In your query, you want to use `COUNT()`.

Try this:

```
SELECT `option`, COUNT(DISTINCT `user`) AS users
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `option`
```

<sub>DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/705a9d/3</sub>

This will show you one row per `option`.  If you want both options across one row, that's a bit trickier.  You'll need to use subqueries for each option.

```
SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`)
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `option` = 'y'
) AS y, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `user`)
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `option` = 'n'
) AS n
```

<sub>DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/705a9d/4</sub>

NOTE: You *can* use `COUNT()` without `GROUP BY`.  That will make the query combine *all* found rows together.